# connect to web service using securecrt tunnel

Tags: port-forwarding, tunnel

**Hi all**

> i have 2 servers. S1 and S2. i can connect to S1 ssh directly but to S2 i can't only ssh from S1 ex:

```
root@S1]: ssh root@S2
connection success
```

i configure web page on S2 and need to connect to it using my laptop. that don't have direct connection to S2. so i used tunnel with port using securecrt and not work:
i put the destination ip and destination port and not work.

```
i configured local port forwarding 
local i put local port:2345
Remote
DEstination host: i put the S2 ip
Port the port of web service http://s2:8060/cci
and save.
but forwarded me to another web page 'production' but i need test web pase 'S2'
```